# In spot color printing, does black count as a spot color?

Tags: color, print-design, pantone, black

Do I have to choose a Pantone black, or can I just use 100% K?

Comment: Is the rest of your design specified as Pantone colors?

Comment: Yes. There are 3 Pantone spot colors (red, green and blue) on the design. Not sure if black will count as a 4th and will have to also be a Pantone swatch, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Black belongs to the set of 14 Pantone Basic colors from which all other PMS colors are mixed:

[image: Pantone solid uncoated book]

If you're using Illustrator, you can find it as a swatch in the PMS color book swatch library

[image: Pantone Solid Coated swatches]

Or in the Color Libraries in Photoshop:

[image: Photoshop Pantone Solid Coated Color Library]

There are other "Blacks" available (Black 2, Black 3, Black 4, Black 5, Black 6, Black 7) but they are all tinted with some other color (yellow, green, orange, red, blue, and silver respectively). Just go with the base black if you want the "blackest" black available.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, black counts as a color. However, you can use 100%k if you'd like.

I've never called out a specific Pantone Black unless there was a reason I wanted *that* Pantone black.

As @JohnB points out, Pantone makes a number of blacks, if you aren't looking for one of those (tinted) blacks, then using 100K is just fine.